# Using CASE in combination with WHERE to specify different columns to filter by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

This probably isn't valid SQL, but this is what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE 
    (CASE @ScoreType 
        WHEN 1 THEN score1 
        WHEN 2 THEN score2 
        ELSE score3 END) >= @Score
```

Basically, I'm trying to filter by different columns in the `WHERE` clause depending on the value of `@ScoreType`. Am I right in guessing that my approach isn't valid? If so, what would be the proper way to go about this?

**edit**: Sorry, I accidentally omitted `end` while simplifying the query to post here. The actual query does have `end`. The query itself runs fine, but the results weren't as expected. It turns out the issue was elsewhere. I suspected the `WHERE` clause because I've never tried anything like this before and was unsure of whether it was valid SQL.

Comment: That looks fine.  Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: The only problem with this approach is que query plan. To optimize your query you can consider using IF statements

Comment: Hi,  try to construct your Query using a SQL string, and then execute it with sp_executesql. I think this should be better in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

this should work maybe?

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE 
    (CASE @ScoreType 
        WHEN 1 THEN score1 
        WHEN 2 THEN score2 
        WHEN 3 THEN score3
      END) >= @Score
```

---

Edit:

I think the problem is: you forgot the `end` to the case

Comment: Isn't this exactly what OP suggested?

Comment: Nope this added `END`

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE (@ScoreType = 1 AND score1 >= @Score) OR 
      (@ScoreType = 2 AND score2 >= @Score) OR
      score3 >= @score
```

**Edit:**

As @HABO pointed out, the above is subtly different to your original code. Replace with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE (@ScoreType = 1 AND score1 >= @Score) OR 
      (@ScoreType = 2 AND score2 >= @Score) OR
      (@ScoreType <> 1 AND @ScoreType  <> 2 AND score3 >= @score)
```

Comment: That has a different meaning than the OP's attempt. If `@ScoreType` is `1` and `score1` is less than `@Score` then the OP's `WHERE` clause will skip the row. Your version will still check for `score3 >= @Score` and might return the row unexpectedly. Put another way: the OP's version always does exactly one comparison between a column and `@Score`, while yours does either one or two.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE @Score <=
    CASE @ScoreType 
        WHEN 1 THEN score1 
        WHEN 2 THEN score2 
        ELSE score3 END
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE
CASE WHEN @ScoreType = 1 THEN score1
WHEN @Scoretype = 2 THEN score2
WHEN @Scoretype = 3 THEN score3
END
```

Not sure what you're trying to achieve with

```
[>= @Score]
```

Thanks for the edit guys, silly mistake on my part.

Comment: where clause syntax error.  The case is the left side, the >= you don't understand is the right side of the where clause.

Comment: your case should have an END @alybaba726