# Using case in where to filter for different table?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL 5.7 I want to filter after a different table column in dependence of a condition beeing true or not.

My initial thought is using a CASE statement that is using a different WHERE condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM example
JOINS ...
WHERE 
    -- brands or market?
    CASE STRCMP ('->', SUBSTRING('Brandname',1,2))
       WHEN 0 THEN mm.ID = 316 -- 'MARKET'
       ELSE b.ID_PARENT IN ('316') -- 'BRAND'
    END
    AND -- other filters
    ...
```

Unfortunatelly this does not work, the query runs forever instead of 100ms with a direct replacement of the case statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM example
JOINS ...
WHERE 
    b.ID_PARENT IN ('316') -- 'BRAND'
    AND -- other filters
    ...
```

It looks like it should work, but it does not. What could be the issue here?

My question is similar to this, but not the same:
[Using CASE in combination with WHERE to specify different columns to filter by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31192316/using-case-in-combination-with-where-to-specify-different-columns-to-filter-by)

Comment: Provide some data sample.

Comment: Actually with sample data in a minimal setup it works. Using the complex full query it does not. This would be really difficult to illustrate it here. My assumption is, that there must be some kind of depriorisation of CASE statements in regards of execution, so the rest of the filter gets executed first and then the case which leads to inacceptable performance. Is this possible?